# parallel processing in R using snow

Tags: r, parallel-processing, lapply, snow, snowfall

I have 1000's of list and each list has multiple time series. I would like to apply forecasting to each element in the list. This has became an intractable problem interms of computing resources. I don't have backgrounder in parallel computing or advanced R programming. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have created dummy list. Basically, dat.list is similar to what I'm working on.

```
library("snow")
library("plyr")
library("forecast")

    ## Create Dummy Data

    z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(30,10,10), 100, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
    lam <- 0.8
    ap <- list(z=z,lam=lam)

## forecast using lapply

    z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(30,10,10), 100, 3), start = c(1971, 1), frequency = 12)
    lam <- 0.5
    zp <- list(z=z,lam=lam)

    dat.list <- list(ap=ap,zp=zp)

    xa <- proc.time()
    tt <- lapply(dat.list,function(x) lapply(x$z,function(y) (forecast::ets(y))))
    xb <- proc.time()
```

The above code gives me what I need. I would like apply parrallel processing to both lapply in the code above.
So I have attempted to use snow package and an example shown in this [site](http://www.r-bloggers.com/quick-guide-to-parallel-r-with-snow/).

```
  ## Parallel Processing


    clus <- makeCluster(3)
    custom.function <- function(x) lapply(x$z,function(y) (forecast::ets(y)))
    clusterExport(clus,"custom.function")

    x1 <- proc.time()
    tm <- parLapply(clus,dat.list,custom.function)
    x2<-proc.time()

    stopCluster(clus)
```

Below are my questions,

1. For some reason, the output of tm is differenct for the non parallel
   version. the forecast function ets is applied to every single data point as opposed to the element in the list.

Non parallel:

```
summary(tt)
   Length Class  Mode
ap 3      -none- list
zp 3      -none- list
```

Parallel Version:

```
    summary(tm)
       Length Class  Mode
    ap 300    -none- list
    zp 300    -none- list
```

2. My second question is how should I parallelize  the lapply in the
   custom function, basically a nested parLapply

   custom.function <- function(x) parLapply(clus,x$z,function(y) (forecast::ets(y))) ## Not working

Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `forecast` package isn't loaded on the cluster workers which causes `lapply` to iterate over the `ts` objects incorrectly. You can load `forecast` on the workers using `clusterEvalQ`:

```
clusterEvalQ(clus, library(forecast))
```

To answer your second question, your attempt at nested parallelism failed because the workers don't have `snow` loaded or `clus` defined. But if you have 1000's of lists then you should have plenty of ways to keep all of your cores busy without worrying about nested parallelism. You're more likely to hurt your performance rather than help it, and it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much Steve. I used llply and .parallel facility which gave me good performance. Can you please suggest any reading material/books on Parallel computing in R for a beginner? Thanks so much

Comment: @forecaster [Luke Tierney's page](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/cluster/cluster.html) has information on snow; `vignette('parallel')` has information on parallel; my book from O'Reilly has information on both. Norman Matloff has an open source textbook on parallel computing (including R) available from his [homepage](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/matloff.html). I also suggest reading the source, especially for high-level functions like parLapply.